# How do i add a "\n" every 6 spaces in a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, split

I have very long strings inside multidimensional arrays. I have been trying to figure out a way to replace every 6th space in each string with a `"\n"` which will cause it to basically press enter.

Example:
orginalString= "i want to put enter after the sixth space of this";

FormatedString = "i want to put enter after **\n** the sixth space of this"

This is what i got so far. Ik its probably completely wrong.

```
public static void FormatArray(String c) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
        if (c.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == 6) {
            counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < Variables.getCards().length; j++) {
                StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder(
                                                    Variables.getCards()[j][1]);
                string.setCharAt(i, '\n');
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one line solution:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\S+\\s+){6}", "$0\n");
```

The replacement term `$0` is the entire match, so this puts back what's matched plus a newline.

If the regex isn't quite to your liking just change it. For example, if you wanted to *replace* the 6th space(s) with a newline, exclude the trailing spaces from the capture:

```
str = str.replaceAll("((\\S+\\s+){5}\\S+)\\s+", "$1\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so

```
// given a String str, replace every sixth space with " \n "
public static String formatString(String str) {
  if (str == null) {                         // Handle null.
    return null;
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    // An output buffer.
  int count = 0;
  for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {        // loop over the characters.
    if (ch == ' ') {                         // test for space.
      count++;
    }
    if (count == 6) {                        // every sixth space.
      count = 0;
      sb.append(" \n");
    }
    sb.append(ch);
  }
  return sb.toString();                      // return the string.
}

// Test it.
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String originalString = "i want to put enter after the sixth space of this";
  String formattedString = "i want to put enter after \n the sixth space of this";
  if (formatString(originalString).equals(
      formattedString)) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
  } else {
    System.out.println("No");
  }
}
```

When I run the above, I get the output -

```
Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quite correct. I suggest the following:

```
public static String formatStr(String a){
    if(a==null) return null;
    String newStr="";
    int len=a.length();
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        newStr+=a.charAt(i);
        if (a.charAt(i) == ' ')counter++;

        if (counter == 6){
            counter=0;
            newStr+="\n";
            //System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}
```

Then you can call formatStr(whatever) and you will get the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
    String pattern = "(\\S*\\s){6}";
    String testString = "This is just a regular test. This is just a regular test. This is just a regular test.";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(testString);
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        strBuilder.append(matcher.group());
        strBuilder.replace(strBuilder.length() - 1, strBuilder.length(), "\n"); // To make it platform independent, user System.lineSeparator() instead of "\n" - only works in Java 7
    }

    if (matcher.hitEnd()) {
        strBuilder.append(testString.substring(strBuilder.length()));
    }

    String newString = strBuilder.toString();
    System.out.println(newString);
```

The output will be:

```
This is just a regular test.
This is just a regular test.
This is just a regular test.
```